# What does the following slokha says about human soul and parabrahman?

Tags: advaita, bhagavata-purana, dvaita

Consider the following verse from  Srimad-Bhagavatam

> bhidyate hṛdaya-granthiś chidyante sarva-saṁśayāḥ kṣīyante cāsya
> karmāṇi dṛṣṭa evātmanīśvare
>
> Thus the knot in the heart is pierced, and all misgivings are cut to
> pieces. The chain of fruitive actions is terminated when one sees the
> **self as master**.
>
> [[21, 12, 1, Srimad-Bhagavatam]](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/1/2/21?d=1)

In the purport by Prabhupada, it is mentioned that

> Attaining scientific knowledge of the Personality of Godhead means
> seeing one's own self simultaneously. As far as the identity of the
> living being as spirit self is concerned, there are a number of
> speculations and misgivings. The materialist does not believe in the
> existence of the spirit self, and **empiric philosophers believe in
> the impersonal feature of the whole spirit without individuality of
> the living beings. But the transcendentalists affirm that the soul and
> the Supersoul are two different identities, qualitatively one but
> quantitatively different.** .............

This paragraph explicitly talked about the three systems of belief

1. Atheists : does not believe in the existence of the spirit self
2. Advaitha : soul and supersoul has no difference
3. Dvaitha : soul and the Supersoul are two different identities, qualitatively one but **quantitatively different**

What is meant by quantitatively different here?

Comment: The third one sounds more Vishishtadvaitic than Dvaitic in nature. It means since Sarvam khalvidam Brahma - everything is Brahman, even souls are qualitatively from Brahman, however Brahman is only 1, whereas individually souls are many (Brahman =1, souls many - quantity difference)

Comment: This sloka reminds me of a verse from Mundaka upanishad. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mundaka-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145117.html          bhidyate hṛdayagranthiśchidyante sarvasaṃśayāḥ |
kṣīyante cāsya karmāṇi tasmindṛṣṭe parāvare || 8 ||

8. When he that is both high and low is seen, the knot of the heart is untied; all doubts are solved; and all his karma is consumed.

Comment: Quantitatively different and qualitatively same means the relationship between drop of water and ocean. Both are the H20 so they are same. This is what is meant by qualitatively same. But one is 0.05 ml and other is some trillion liters, this quantitatively different. So a soul and God are of the same essence, same material, but soul is limited and small but God is infinite. This is my understanding of Vishishtadvaita.

Comment: Also there seems to multiple versions of the same verse which gives different meanings look here https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/20/30/

Comment: Also this verse here quoted Ishware eva Atmani Dhrsta, can't it also mean that when Atman is seen in Ishwara?? There seems to a possible different translation. Ishware means in Ishwara. So is another translation possible?

Comment: It's not  dvitic statement please correct it to vasista Advaitic please fo know dvaita says soul is not qualitative and qualitative one they are completely different

Comment: Here the worc of atman is contextual in this context atman is paramatman  I.e. Supreme soul we have supreme soul as antaryami inside individual soul  the antartami same in all and pervading but individual souls are not

Comment: When one sees antaryami  as doer of action then fruits of action ceases